# Django. How to create new model, with specific fields (in dropdown) from django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Im working on page with car ads. But I want to let admin extend the page in the future, let him add from django admin site new category of ads - houses for instance. 
I know how to let admin create new ad in existing category,
but how to let admin to create new category with new fields (int, str, Boolean)?
Thanx for anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Category model:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

This is the advertisement model

```
class Adv(models.Model):
    your fields here
    category = models.ForeignKey()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an app for adding Schools see the following images for refrence.
[image]

when I click on "Add" against Schools following screen follows
[image]

after filling in the necessary details click Save and the School is successfully added!
[image]
[image]

You should be able to do this with any model you created

Unfortunately I can't share the code the company won't allow but I may be able to help you if you pasted your models.py and the corresponding template. You will also need some javascript to do this. If you are trying to do something like this I may be of help.